# jQuery animation and timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm technically new to jQuery and I'm trying to implement as much of it in my codes to get used to it.

So I'm trying to make a div to move up the page and change opacity to 1 when the user clicks anywhere on the page.

here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#body").click(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#name").animate(function() {
                bottom:"500px";
                opacity:"1";
            }, 1000);
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Note that `name` is the id of the div I'm trying to animate and `body` is just an id I gave to the body of the HTML page so that the action is triggered when clicking anywhere blank on the page.

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: Just google "jQuery" and "timer" and your will find: http://api.jquery.com/delay/ and like the first answer said: opacity goes from 0 to 1 if the element has no opacity 0 sets by a css rule. you will see nothing

Comment: I'm not that dump to forget to set opacity to 0 in the CSS people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would execute the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function as if it were CSS. You are adding semi colons to your animate properties where they should be comma's.

```
$("#wrap").on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#name").animate({
            bottom:"500px",
            opacity:"1"
        }, 1000);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/CQEvW/1/)

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me the best. However, it turned out that the mistake came from the HTML (wrong id usage).

Comment: Somethign to do with #body I assume. Doh! Anyway, if you found me helpful could you at least upvote this answer or mark it as correct :) Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Properties of an object should be separated by a comma, not semi-colon. Also, animate takes an object, not a function. Try this:

```
$("#name").animate({
    bottom: "500px",
    opacity: "1"
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! Totally forgot that :p

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make the opacity go from 0 to 1, you have to set it to 0 initially in css. Just animating it to 1 when it's already 1 will do nothing!